# Confirmação com modal do Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-3

Tenho um sistema do qual estou usando o Bootstrap. Gostaria de saber se tem como nas ações de cadastrar, em vez de aparecer a famosa frase "Seu cadastro foi efetuado com êxito!" do alert do Javascript, aparecer em Modal do Bootstrap.

Comment: Não entendi, essa mensagem não é lançada por você?

Comment: O cadastramento ocorre normalmente, porém estou usando o alert do próprio Javascript. Gostaria de que ao invés de usar o alert do Javascript, a mensagem aparecesse no modal do Bootstrap. Atualmente, tenho que clicar no link para aparecer o modal do Bootstrap, porém preciso que ao fazer o cadastro, retornasse a mensagem no modal e não no alert do Javascript.

Comment: Poste o que já tem tentado.

Comment: Na verdade não tentei nada ainda, pois nem sei por onde começar rs rs. O que está pronto é o cadastro, insert do mysql, essas coisas. Porém quando é feito o cadastro, aparece a mensagem em javascript. É essa mensagem que preciso mudar para o modal do Bootstrap.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar para abrir via js:

```
$('#myModal').modal('show');
```

```js
$(function() {
  $('#openModal').click(function() {
     $('#myModal').modal('show');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Modal Example</h2>
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" id="openModal">Open Modal</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Na verdade o seu código Emir funciona ao clicar no botão.

Comment: Consegui arrumar uma solução aqui mesmo no Stack e editei  minha pergunta com o link do tópico.

Comment: Use o $('#myModal').modal('show'); para mostrar sem clicar no botão. Coloquei o botão apenas para facilitar o exemplo

Answer (score 0):

Consegui arrumar a solução aqui mesmo no Stack. Quem quiser uma solução parecida, veja esse [Tópico](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/51835/como-exibir-uma-janela-modal-de-confirma%C3%A7%C3%A3o-ap%C3%B3s-o-cadastro-ser-conclu%C3%ADdo)

```
    <div id="myModa3" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"  aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
```

Jquery:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#myModa3').modal();
    });
```

A solução foi do colega Caio Silva.

Obrigado a todos!

Comment: Se possível, e não for pedir demais, adicione o código na resposta. Não tem problema ser de outro tópico, apenas adicione a fonte e tudo fica resolvido.
Sei que estou sendo chato, mas fica melhor para a comunidade assim.